# Can I create a git hook that changes the branch I'm committing to?

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface, githooks

I often find myself working on a feature branch and stumble upon a "general fix" I want to make that isn't related to this feature, but rather to the general dev branch (e.g. fix some styling, refactor something, etc).

So what I need to do is to stash my current progress, switch to the dev branch, make the change, commit it, go back to my original branch and apply my the latest stash. Now since this is a really repetitive and annoying task I was really hoping there would be a way to do such a thing using a commit hook based on the commit message. Basically I imagined it would be if I'm committing something with a message that starts with `##dev`, it would automatically know to do the process above.

Do you guys think its possible?

Thanks a lot in advance, Alex Z. :)

Comment: How could a hook know what general change you have to make to the dev branch?  Is it really such a hassle to stash, switch branches, and make the fix?

Comment: You could always reset your feature branch back to where it should be, and you could also re-apply the commits from the feature branch to the right branch. `git reset --hard`, `git cherry-pick` and `git rebase` can easily do the job.

Comment: An easy way to switch back to your feature branch: `git checkout -`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was hoping to be able to specify this by appending ##dev to the commit message...

Answer (score 0):

> I was hoping to be able to specify this by appending ##dev to the commit message

Only a **[`commit-msg` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_committing_workflow_hooks)** *might* have the opportunity to block the commit if you are on the wrong branch. I don't think at this stage of the commit it could change branch though.

If you have any way to identify you are working on a feature, then you can use a similar setup [as this gist](https://gist.github.com/stefansundin/9059706) in order to detect the current branch and cancel the commit if you are on the wrong one.

```
BRANCH=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

if [[ "$BRANCH" == "master" || "$BRANCH" == "develop" ]]; then
  echo "You are on branch $BRANCH. Are you sure you want to commit to this branch?"
  echo "If so, commit with -n to bypass this pre-commit hook."
  exit 1
fi
```